# vb.net deleting lots of dynamically created buttons

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, runtime, controls

I'm a new programmer to vb.net, so apologise for what is likely to be ignorance.
I’m building a simple gui for a database interface, with many parent and child items within it. Upon a form I create buttons depending on how many items (parents/children). I've got the creation of the buttons thus:

```
For RowNumber As Integer = 0 To NoOfRows
        Dim Buttoni As New Button
        Buttoni.Location = New Point(LocationX, LocationY)
        Buttoni.Width = 100
        Buttoni.Height = 40
        Buttoni.Visible = True
        Buttoni.Text = DatasetA.Tables(0).Rows(RowNumber).Item("Name")
        ButtonName = "Button" + RowNumber.ToString

        If LocationX < FormWidth - (SpacePerButtonX * 2) Then
            LocationX = LocationX + SpacePerButtonX
        Else
            LocationX = 50
            LocationY = LocationY + SpacePerButtonY
        End If

        AddHandler Buttoni.Click, AddressOf DynamicButtonClick
        Me.Controls.Add(Buttoni)
        Buttoni.BringToFront()  'brings newest buttons to front!
    Next
```

But I’m struggling with a way to delete the buttons to make way for a new set to replace them... I can delete a single one upon its click, but I’d like to delete all of the buttons that have been created in this way before re-creating them.

I hope that makes sense and there is a fairly simple way to accomplish this..?

Comment: VB.NET in what environment? WPF? Winforms? WebForms? WP7? Silverlight? MVC?

Answer (score 3):

I will add, in your creation loop, some value to the Tag property.
This will help to differentiate the buttons created dinamically from the buttons created statically in your form.

```
Buttoni.Tag = 1
```

Then, to delete a button, loop in reverse order on the Me.Controls collection,
check if you get a button and if the Tag property IsNot Nothing

```
For x as Integer = Me.Controls.Count - 1 to 0 step -1)
    Dim b as Button = TryCast(Me.Controls(x), Button)
    If b IsNot Nothing AndAlso b.Tag IsNot Nothing then
        b.Dispose()       '' NOTE: disposing the button also removes it
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for your edit. Care to elaborate on the nasty leak? I'm not aware of this and I have some code that does the Remove. A link is enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4195285/17034  and a bunch of questions you'll find from searching "error creating window handle"

Comment: @HansPassant thank you again, that's huge, how have I missed this for all this time? Tomorrow will be a cleaning day at work.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you want to do.  I guess you could just use the same technique in reverse, something like

```
        For i As Integer = Me.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim ctrl = Me.Controls(i)

            If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Button Then
               ctrl.Dispose()           '' NOTE: disposing the control also removes it
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and delete it with double click!
Easy Code :

```
Dim b As New Button
Private btn As Button ' this is a reference object
Private ptX, ptY As Integer
Private drag As Boolean
Private Sub nodebtn_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Clicks = 2 Then
        b.Dispose()
    End If

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        drag = True
        btn = CType(sender, Button)
        ptX = e.X : ptY = e.Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub nodebtn_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If drag Then
        btn.Location = New Point(btn.Location.X + e.X - ptX, btn.Location.Y + e.Y - ptY)
        Me.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub nodebtn_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    drag = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    b.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    b.Size = New Size(110, 29)
    b.BringToFront()
    b.Text = "Button"
    AddHandler b.MouseDown, AddressOf nodebtn_MouseDown
    AddHandler b.MouseMove, AddressOf nodebtn_MouseMove
    AddHandler b.MouseUp, AddressOf nodebtn_MouseUp
    Me.Controls.Add(b)
End Sub
```