# Destroying Controls VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, destroy

I'm having trouble destroying all of the controls after I've dynamically made them. I'm using this to destroy them:

```
For Each cControl In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
                Me.Controls.Remove(cControl)
            End If
        Next
        For Each cControl1 In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf cControl1 Is CheckBox) Then
                Me.Controls.Remove(cControl1)
            End If
        Next
```

I've also used `cControl.dispose()` instead of `Me.Controls.Remove(cControl)`.

Instead of going through and destroying all textboxes and checkboxes, it'll only destroy every other checkbox and the textboxes. If I switch the two For loops around, it'll be the other way around. Is there a fix for this? An explanation? Work around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net deleting lots of dynamically created buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865183/vb-net-deleting-lots-of-dynamically-created-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the `Controls` collection when you're iterating that collection. And you can join the too loops. This will solve your problem:

```
Dim count As Integer = Me.Controls.Count

For i As Integer = count -1 to 0 Step -1 
    Dim cControl As Control = Me.Controls(i)

    If (TypeOf cControl Is CheckBox OrElse TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
        Me.Controls.Remove(cControl)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I actually just found a work around that does, essentially, the same thing your code does - plus it works!

                For i As Integer = Me.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If (TypeOf Me.Controls(i) Is TextBox) Or (TypeOf Me.Controls(i) Is CheckBox) Then
                    Me.Controls.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next

I'll +1 your answer Alireza, thanks!

Comment: A clever use of `RemoveAt` of course. That is better than my answer :)

Comment: You also have a little error in your code. You define `cControl` but check the type of `cControl1`. :-)

Comment: Oh! I'm gonna kill myself :-D thanks for telling me :)